# Spring MVC: restful URL not found but resource URL works

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have one Spring MVC project, it serves one Restful servlet, and one static website (which is placed in `/WebContent/portal/`.

**Restful URI**: like for `/service/login`, its controller is placed in `com.test.testap.restful.auth`

**Static resource URLS**: uses `<mvc:resources mapping="/portal/**" location="/portal/" />` to serve static files like **index.html**.

**The problem I met**:

**Scenario 1**: When removes `<mvc:resources mapping="/portal/**" location="/portal/" />`, Restful API URLs works fine. But can't access the `/portal/index.html` which is expected.

**Scenario 2**: When adds `<mvc:resources mapping="/portal/**" location="/portal/" />`, `/portal/index.html` works, but returns Http Status=404 for all Restful URI.

**PS:** you will see `<mvc:resources mapping="/portal/**" location="/portal/" />` at the end of the file `WEB-INF/spring/test-restful-servlet.xml`.

It seems when adds `<mvc:resources>`, it will caused all urls (including Restful URLs will be served as resources). But can't find anything I did wrong.

I tried many solutions but all of them don't work (like declare another servlet for `url-pattern=/portal/*`)

Appreciate any help.

Below is my configuration files:

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Restful Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test-restful</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/test-restful-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>        
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test-restful</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**WEB-INF/spring/test-restful-servlet.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.testap.restful.controller, com.test.testap.restful.auth" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
    </bean>

<bean id="stringConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
<property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
                <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
        </list>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="jsonConverter"
class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
                <ref bean="stringConverter"/>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
</property>
</bean>
<import resource="db-connectors.xml" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/portal/**" location="/portal/" />
</beans>
```

Below is the dependencies declared at **pom.xml**:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration test-restful-servlet.xml add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
```

declares support for annotation driven components.